# Merge multiple files into one file + insert break line between files

Tags: python, cmd

i want to add an insert break line after merging all the text file's content together, but code not working. the intent is use simple cmd command and run it as a python script with while loop. pls advise.

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\CL\test' #folder with 3 .txt files
os.chdir(path)
os.system('cmd /k "copy *.txt result.txt "') #missing command to insert line break
```

```
sample file content
123|abc|def
```

```
-current content in result.txt-
123|abc|def|234|abc|def|345|abc|def
```

```
-envision outcome-
123|abc|def
234|abc|def
345|abc|def
```

thank you!

Comment: What is an "insert break line"? What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is no file named `results.txt` being produced? Is it being produced but doesn't look the way you want it to look? What would the final result file look like? Can you share sample and desired results?

Comment: @JNevill sorry pls see edited post. have included sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to get the text files in your `path` first. Then you're going to want to read each file and copy its contents into your `results.txt` file and add a new line `\n` between each file.

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\CL\test'
# Get only files in test directory
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]

# Create results.txt file
with open(r'C:\Users\CL\test\results.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    # Iterate through all files
    for f in onlyfiles:
        # Open file
        with open(f) as file:
            # Copy lines of file into output_file
            for line in file:
                output_file.write(line)
        # Write line break between files
        output_file.write('\n')
```